# Golang GORM embedded struct

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to join and preload 2 table and combine the result, but I could not get the desired result.

models.go

```
type Product struct {
    ID          uint   `json:"-"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
}

type TransactionItem struct {
    ID        uint `json:"-"`
    ProductID uint `json:"-"`
    Qty       int  `json:"qty"`
    Price     int  `json:"price"`
    Product   // I want to combine properties of Product into Transaction Item
}
```

controllers.go

```
var items []TransactionItem
if e := db.Preload("Product").Find(&items).Error; e != nil {
    log.Println(e)
}
```

Desired result:

```
[
  {
     "qty": 1,
     "price": 50,
     "name": "Product name",
     "description": "This is the product description"
  }, { ... }
]
```

I have tried using "gorm:foreigKey=ProductID;references=ID;embedded;embeddedPrefix:product", and switching and trying out different combinations but still could not get the product.name and product.description to merge the data to TransactionItem. If I change Transaction Item to this:

```
type TransactionItem struct {
    ID        uint `json:"-"`
    ProductID uint `json:"-"`
    Qty       int  `json:"qty"`
    Price     int  `json:"price"`
    Product   Product 
}

//This will work and display data from product table, but the result is as follow:
[
  {
     "qty": 1,
     "price": 50,
     "product": {
       "name": "Product name",
       "description": "This is the product description"
     }
  }, { ... }
]
```

I can achieve the desired result by looping this result and manually set the name & description, but I think there should be a way for GORM to automatically do this, right? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your desired result where the `Product` fields are embedded directly within the `TransactionItem` in the resulting JSON, you have to use embedded structs and alias the embedded struct fields with the desired JSON field names.

Given the following structs, GORM automatically embeds the fields of the `Product` struct into `TransactionItem`:

```golang
type Product struct {
    ID          uint   `json:"-"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
}

type TransactionItem struct {
    ID        uint `json:"-"`
    ProductID uint `json:"-"`
    Qty       int  `json:"qty"`
    Price     int  `json:"price"`
    Product   `gorm:"foreignKey:ProductID"` // Embed Product struct
}
```

When GORM loads a `TransactionItem`, it should automatically load and embed the corresponding `Product` without the need to explicitly call `Preload("Product")`.

However, this will generate the JSON structure like this:

```json
{
    "qty": 1,
    "price": 50,
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Product name",
    "Description": "This is the product description"
}
```

To generate your desired JSON structure, you would need to add JSON field tags to alias the fields of the embedded `Product` struct in the `TransactionItem` struct, like this:

```golang
type TransactionItem struct {
    ID          uint `json:"-"`
    ProductID   uint `json:"-"`
    Qty         int  `json:"qty"`
    Price       int  `json:"price"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`        // Alias for Product.Name
    Description string `json:"description"` // Alias for Product.Description
    Product     `gorm:"foreignKey:ProductID"` // Embed Product struct
}
```

This should generate your desired JSON structure:

```json
{
    "qty": 1,
    "price": 50,
    "name": "Product name",
    "description": "This is the product description"
}
```

Remember to run this loading code without explicit preloading:

```golang
var items []TransactionItem
if e := db.Find(&items).Error; e != nil {
    log.Println(e)
}
```

And note that this technique aliases the `Product` fields in `TransactionItem`, effectively overwriting them, so it's crucial to ensure there are no naming collisions between the fields in `Product` and `TransactionItem`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use embedded to achieve that, if I'm not mistaken. It will merge the two struct instead of treating it as relationship, then you do your preload. Like the following:

```golang
type Author struct {
  Name  string
  Email string
}

type Blog struct {
  ID      int
  Author  Author `gorm:"embedded"` // <-- Use this
  Upvotes int32
}

// equals
type Blog struct {
  ID    int64
  Name  string
  Email string
  Upvotes  int32
}
```

**Note:** Code not tested.

For more information about embedded, read more [here](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Embedded-Struct).

Comment: Yes that's what I thought too but apparently this producing the same result, not the desired result

Answer (score 0):

If this does not work:

```golang
type TransactionItem struct {
    ID              uint `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"-"`
    ProductID       uint `gorm:"column:product_id" json:"-"`
    Qty             int  `gorm:"column:qty" json:"qty"`
    Price           int  `gorm:"column:price" json:"price"`
    Product         Product `gorm:"foreignKey:ProductID;references:ID;embedded;embeddedPrefix:product_"`
}
```

That would mean/illustrate GORM does not support directly merging embedded struct fields into the parent struct during the query. The ["embedded" feature](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#embedded_struct) in GORM is more about table structure and not about customizing query results.

To achieve your desired output, you would have to do this programmatically after fetching the records.

```golang
var items []TransactionItem
if e := db.Preload("Product").Find(&items).Error; e != nil {
    log.Println(e)
}

type ResponseItem struct {
    Qty         int    `json:"qty"`
    Price       int    `json:"price"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
}

var response []ResponseItem
for _, item := range items {
    response = append(response, ResponseItem{
        Qty:         item.Qty,
        Price:       item.Price,
        Name:        item.Product.Name,
        Description: item.Product.Description,
    })
}

// Now `response` will have the desired structure
// You can then marshal it to JSON for your response
```

With a new struct `ResponseItem`, to match your desired JSON structure.

After fetching the `TransactionItem` slice, I iterate over it to create a new slice of `ResponseItem`, taking the `Product.Name` and `Product.Description` fields and setting them in the new `ResponseItem` instances.

Comment: I actually also did something like this for the workaround, but I'm hoping something less tedious and fewer codes that is built-in from GORM itself.

Comment: @Charas I understand, and hope as well that your bounty will attract a better answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer though, if there's no better answer in 3 days I will give the bounty to you for the effort and for the closest best answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to achieve the result:

```
var items []TransactionItem

db.Joins("JOIN products ON transaction_items.product_id = products.id").
    Select("transaction_items.qty, transaction_items.price, products.name, products.description").
    Find(&items)
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to use join as it defeats the whole purpose of it, it must use Preload