# GoLang GORM embedding struct from other table

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have 3 models, one embedded to another:

```
// same with db table "users" struct except UserEmail embedded
type User struct {
    ID      string `json:"id"`
    EmailID string `json:"-"`

    *UserEmail `json:",inline" gorm:"foreignKey:EmailID;references:UserEmailID"`
}

// not same with db table "email" struct
type UserEmail struct {
    UserEmailID string `json:"-"`
    UserEmail   string `json:"user_email"`
}

// same with db table "email" struct
type Email struct {
    ID    string `json:"id"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
}
```

I need preload data from 2 tables called users and emails.

My preload code looks like this, but cause error "ERROR: column users.email_id does not exist (SQLSTATE 42703)":

```
err = db.ORM.Model(&Users{}).
    Preload("UserEmail", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Model(&Email{}).Select("id as user_email_id, email as user_email")
    }).
    Find(&resp).Error
```

Comment: This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77157922/19357793) looks close, but I need preload struct that is different from my models.Email

Comment: why you added `json:"-"`

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV because I don't wont send this fields in response

Comment: If you just got started you should learn pure sql. My tutor advised me not to use gorm or any other orm library. Now I am sure that he was correct

Comment: I now basics of sql, but thanks for advice. I need solution for this issue because we already use GORM in our business project and it clearly solve our problems. Some times before we made preloads manually trough funcs TakeUserEmail and etc through Go, but now I start refactoring and looking for such cases and their solutions

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV I also read documentation. It shows few examples, but don't explain how it works and which dependencies it need for such cases (I mean, clearly explains all underwater rocks). I guess it can't solve my case at all. May be Raw sql will be good, but now we have at least 5k lines of code for work with db. Raw SQL may be make it more than 15k and it is not good for 3 back end devs

Answer (score 0):

can you provide the schema database, maybe the information will be very useful to help your problem.

`ERROR: column users.email_id does not exist (SQLSTATE 42703)`
indicates the column `email_id` **does not exist** in your `users` table.

I think the column name is not `email_id` but `user_email_id` in your schema DB. Maybe your table `users` schema like this:

```
| users           |
| --------------- |
| id              |
| user_email_id   |
```

and schema table `user_emails` like this:

```
| user_emails     |
| --------------- |
| id              |
| email           |
```

If my database schema guess is correct, Maybe the fix would be something like this:

```golang
type User struct {
    ID        string     `json:"id"`
    EmailID   string     `json:"-" gorm:"column:user_email_id"`
    UserEmail *UserEmail `json:",inline" gorm:"foreignKey:EmailID;references:UserEmailID"`
}

type UserEmail struct {
    UserEmailID string `json:"-" gorm:"column:id"`
    UserEmail   string `json:"user_email" gorm:"column:email"`
}
```

Add tag [Column Name](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#Column-Name) to keep your name struct attributes, and your preload don't need query sql alias for casting column `id as user_email_id` because already use tag Column Name, and the final code like this:

```golang
err = db.ORM.Model(&User{}).Preload("UserEmail").Find(&resp).Error
```

Comment: Yes, your guess is correct, but field name is email_id. Your code work fine for named field UserEmail, but json tag inline works only with embedded (anonymous) fields, and how I see, preload from other tables don't work for embedded fields. Here I got stuck

Comment: For now I am already using your solution (with some little differences) but will wait for xmas miracle

Comment: Okay, glad to hear you got insight from my answer @SunatSaidov